# Is it possible to change project type for VC++ prj after creation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I created console type project, but now see what i need win32 type. Is it possible to change it on the fly?

Real reason is what i need to have hInstance to run my window, so i need entry point like this:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer to your real question is: You do not need the `hInstance` parameter passed to `_tWinMain`. [`GetModuleHandle(NULL);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199.aspx) returns the same thing.

To answer the question as asked: Changing a console application to a GUI application is as simple as specifying a different subsystem using the [/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) linker option and providing the appropriate entry point (as called by the CRT). The linker will select the correct entry point according to the /SUBSYSTEM option, if it hasn't been explicitly set. If you changed the entry point you will have to update it using the [/ENTRY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx) linker option as well.

All options can be accessed through the Visual Studio GUI, or changed manually in the respective *.vcproj files.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no wizard or built-in tool to do so. At least not in the Visual Studio versions I've used (up to VS2008).

You can do it by hand, editing all the parts that are different. You can create an empty project of the new type, and copy anything that's different into your code.

However, I think I would go the other way around. I would create a new empty project of the type you need and copy there all the code/settings you have already created.

Comment: I think it is not so simple to extract this code settings, though.. It may be placed in different parts of the sln or prj files.